# a link to display more details

Tags: php

I have been trying to build an event page on a website that am creating for my final year project. I wanted the home event page to show a less detailed list of events with titles. 
The event titles are supposed to serve as links that are to open up a page that show a more detailed description of the event a user decides to click on or select.
I managed to create a link on every event title but can't seem to correctly link it the to a page that would show a detailed description of the selected event.

**my event.php page has the code:**

```
<?php
include'session.php';
include"database.php";


//Retrieves data from MySQL 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data
 //Echo "<img src=http://localhost/trial_Admin/events/" .$info['photo'] ."> <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Name:</b> <a href='more_details.php/?name='$name''/ >".$info['name']. "</a><br>";
 Echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$info['email'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Phone:</b> ".$info['phone'] . " <hr>"; 
 }
?>
```

**And the more_details.php**

```
<?php
include'session.php';
include"database.php";


$name=$_GET['name'];
    //Retrieves data from MySQL 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data
 Echo "<img src=http://localhost/trial_Admin/events/" .$info['photo'] ."> <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Name:</b> <a href=''/ >".$info['name']. "</a><br>";
 Echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$info['email'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Phone:</b> ".$info['phone'] . " <hr>"; 
    }


?>
```

Comment: I really need your help to solve this problem. My idea was to create an event page that is similar to that of the Eventbrite Website.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the id of the event in your db since it's the unique identifier. Change that in your events.php page.

Comment: if you did stick with name you need to use url_decode() to replace + with spaces etc..  ALSO lookup SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is because of this line

```
Echo "<b>Name:</b> <a href='more_details.php/?name='$name''/ >".$info['name']. "</a><br>";
```

change it to

```
Echo "<b>Name:</b> <a href='more_details.php/?name=".urlencode($info['name'])."'/ >".$info['name']. "</a><br>";
```

But using using an ID would be much better ie having a url like the following

```
Echo "<b>Name:</b> <a href='more_details.php/?id=$info['id']'/ >".$info['name']. "</a><br>";
```